# different text-sizes inside td-cell on mobile (iphone 5)

Tags: html, css, viewport

On my iphone (orientation landscape) i get different font-sizes inside my table-cells.

Page:
https://el.atelierscheidegger.ch/index.html

I tried different media-queries and viewport settings but did not get the result i wanted, see image here: https://el.atelierscheidegger.ch/img/IMG_6655.PNG
"Prix Henry REynaud Canada" and "Museo Internationale, Faenza/Italien" have different sizes, even if they are defined the same.

I am thankful for any advice.

Comment: looks okay from here...

Comment: I could fix the issue with adding this to td { -webkit-text-size-adjust: 100%; }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you did not update the version of css in the code after making the changes or did not clean your cache before checking for updated version of a page.
I've tried looking onto the website and the fonts are the same size, as they are supposed to be.
[image]